# Reading Into GSON for list of top level tags

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following (obfuscated for SO) JSON:

```
{
 "ABC" : {
  "logo_1": {
    "hdpi": "value",
    "mdpi": "value",
    "xhdpi": "value",
    "xxhdpi": "value"
  },
  "logo_2": {
    "regular": "value",
    "high_res": "value",
  }
},
"XYZ" : {
  "logo_1": {
    "hdpi": "value",
    "mdpi": "value",
    "xhdpi": "value",
    "xxhdpi": "value"
  },
  "logo_2": {
    "regular": "value",
    "high_res": "value",
  }
}
```

ABC and XYZ are regions.  We need different logos per region and the problem I am hitting is that I want to be able to handle new regions in the future.  Therefore I don't want to create an object such as the following:

```
public class EnvoyMessagesModel {

    public Region ABC;
    public Region XYZ;

}
```

I've seen lists used in Gson but the name of the list variable is always the actual tag and since "ABC" != "XYZ" I don't think that would work.  Is there a way to just get a list of these regions that will know their top level tag as well?  I would want to do something like region.getTopLevel() and have it return "ABC" or "XYZ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that...

- Region names are all different.
- Logo names in a given region are all different.
- Logo's attribute names in a given logo are all different.

... the most flexible way to parse your JSON I can think of would be using `Map` classes. Something like:

```
Type mapType = 
    new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>() {}.getType();

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> regionsMap = 
    new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString, mapType);
```

Then, if you want to get all the region names, you can do just:

```
Set<String> regionNames = regionsMap.keySet();
```

... or if you want the value `"regular"` of the logo `"logo_2"` of the region `"XYZ"`, you can do...

```
String regular = regionsMap.get("XYZ").get("logo_2").get("regular");
```

... and so on...